# Не могу найти ошибку . Язык С

Tags: c

Написал код, суть в том, что вводим 30 элементов(от 1 до 30) и по идее вывод должен быть: 28,29,30 , а выводит 27 28 29, то есть берет мусор и так же , если дифайн 6 будет, что не так с кодом?
Определить три последовательных элемента, сумма которых максимальна, в числовом массиве из 30 элементов.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define N 30
int main(void)
{
    int a[N];
    int i, k; // счетчики 
    int s, max, imax; // сумма, максимальное значение s, позиция первого элемента
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("vvedite element massiva a[%d] = ", i); // вводим элементы массива с клавиатуры
        scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++) printf("%-3d", a[i]); // вывод всех элементов массива на экран
    printf("\n\n");
    int n = N - 3; 
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) // ищем максимальную сумму и запоминаем номер первого элемента суммы
    {
        for (k = s = 0; k<3; k++) // до какого элемента в массиве проверяем?
        s += a[i + k];
        if (i == 0) max = s, imax = i;
        else if (s > max) max = s, imax = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    printf("elementi:%3d\n", a[i + imax]); // выводим три элемента с максимальной суммой 
}
```

Comment: *off-by-one error*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: Ошибка в строке `int n = N - 3;`. Должно быть `int n = N - 2;`

Comment: Объясните почему N - 2?

Comment: Если массив `a` состоит из `N` элементов, то индекс последнего элемента равен `N-1`. Если массив `a` состоит из `N-3` элементов, то индекс последнего элемента равен `N-4`. На последней итерации цикла `i` переменная `i` равна `N-4`. И в цикле `k` вы перебираете три элемента, начиная с элемента с индексом `N-4`, т.е. вы перебираете три элемента с индексами `N-4`, `N-3` и `N-2`. Таким образом, последний элемент массива `a`, имеющий индекс `N-1` обработан не будет!

Comment: С другой стороны, если массив `a` имеет `N-2` элементов, то его последний элемент имеет индекс `N-3` и на последней итерации цикла `i` переменная `i` будет равна `N-3`, а значит в цикле `k` вы обработаете 3 элемента массива `a`, начинающиеся с индекса `N-3`, т.е. элементы с индексами `N-3`, `N-2` и `N-1`, т.е. вы успешно обработаете последнюю тройку элементов массива `a`.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так, только верните N 30

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define N 5
int main()
{
int a[N];
int sum, s_max, i_max; // текущая сумма, максимальная сумма, позиция последнего 
                       // элемента из трех с максимальной суммой
int i;

for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
{
    printf("vvedite element massiva a[%d] = ", i); // вводим элементы массива с клавиатуры
    scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
    printf("%-3d", a[i]); // вывод всех элементов массива на экран
printf("\n\n");

s_max = a[0] + a[1] + a[2];
i_max = 2;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (a[i] >= 2)
    {
        sum = a[i] + a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];
        if (sum > s_max)
        {
            s_max = sum;
            i_max = i + 1;
        }
    }
}

printf("max summa elementov s %d po %d = %d", i_max - 2, i_max, s_max);
}
```

Извиняюсь за правки, теперь работает)